# Why does the Lockheed D-21B have three air data probes?

Tags: pitot-static

The [Lockheed D-21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_D-21) has three air data booms / pitot intake tubes: one on the nose and one on each wing. (Images [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3c/B-52_with_D-21.jpg) and [here](http://airforcelive.dodlive.mil/files/2014/09/Locheed-D-21B.jpg).)

All three appear to be pitot-static tubes. Anyone know what purpose having three of these served?

Comment: most testing/experimental aircraft have wide arrays of extra sensors hanging off them in different positions.

Comment: As an autonomous vehicle it needed three probes to enable the FCS to "vote" what the correct signal is if one probe shows erroneous readings.

Comment: Peter, since the three probes are in different positions, presumably they would have different readings. A small sideslip, for example, would result in three different yet valid readings, correct?

Comment: @ToddStellanova No, parallel probes will read the same value even if in a sideslip. It is easy to see if you make a drawing.